# pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and the pymysql module to extract data from a MySQL database. I keep getting the error (at the bottom) when I execute the following code to select data (the error follows execution of the query):

```
conn = pms.connect(Host,User,Pwd,DB)
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()  # Create cursor to interact with MySQL
    cur.execute(query)
```

where the query is:

```
SELECT  Time,var1,var2,var3 FROM tableName WHERE Time BETWEEN '2017-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-15 00:00:00'
```

I am happy to post more of the code but it's very large so better to try and narrow down what might be causing the problem first I think.

This problem only occurs when I try to extract large(ish) amounts of data (tens of millions of rows). In this case I am extracting 4 variables, including Time, from 100 Hz sample rate data. The primary key in the database table is the Time.

**FYI**: I am able to perform a similar request to MySQL using the COUNT command on the same time period with no error:

```
SELECT COUNT(Time) FROM tableName WHERE Time BETWEEN '2017-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-15 00:00:00'
```

**Theory 1:** Judging from google results of this problem, I suspect that it may be a threading related issue arising from my use of the GUI. But I am not consciously creating any threads within this program. Having said that, I am learning as I go and may be naive to it.

**Theory 2:** Another suspicion is that when the file size exceeds a threshold limit, something in the way the data is read from MySQL changes. Perhaps new threads/connections are created to deal with the request and an error occurs because of limitations associated with pymysql's Threadsafety value of 1 (according to googling the problem).

**Question:** Could the connection time out after say 15 minutes?

**Key points:**

- The MySQL query works fine if I type it into MySQL command prompt
- The code works fine for small datasets (~1 or 2 million rows)
- The error occurs when I start to extract larger data sets (tens of millions of rows or more)
- The error does not occur immediately, the line will run and the error occurs after maybe 15 minutes
- I am able to perform a similar request to mysql like a COUNT with large datasets with no error
- The code forms part of a tkinter GUI
- I open and close connections to the database a few times throughout the code, always using a 'with conn' statement so it is closed when I am done.
- I get the same error when extracting large amounts of data from other tables, with only 2 variables, or with up to 150 variables.

**Error information:** Below is the full error for your information. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1578, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "M:/HKerr/python/DBread/DBread_27_v2/DBread_27.py", line 108, in <module>
    TimeB.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),Columns,Host)
  File "M:/HKerr/python/DBread/DBread_27_v2\DBread_mdl_27.py", line 222, in MySQLread
    count+=1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 842, in __exit__
    self.rollback()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 793, in rollback
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 767, in _read_ok_packet
    pkt = self._read_packet()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1001, in _read_packet
    % (packet_number, self._next_seq_id))
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 185 expected 1
```

Comment: Your connection seems to be closed premature: To test this theory: Remove your session close from the code and keep an eye on the processlist in the databases.

Comment: Hey @Norbert van Nobelen. Thanks. I just took the "with conn:" out so that the conn was not being closed I got a "MemoryError".
It was my impression that using "with conn:", my connection will only be closed once the 'cur.execute' had been completed, but something has changed!
But, if the problem was that I am somehow closing the connection, why did it work for small file sizes? It's progress, but my execute query still did not complete! I monitored the processlist in MySQL and the query was sent to mySQL with both versions of the code. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Did the query stay alive until you ran into the memory issue? (That memory issue is just telling me that you need to manage/segment your data (ie: The way you process the data once you take it from the cursor/data life cycle in the app))

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen. Yes the query stayed alive. Regarding that mwmory issue, I solved it. I was somehow using 32 bit python on this computer! So I switched to 64 bit and managed to extract 200million rows of 4 variables fine. The code uses far too much RAM!! but it works. I need to optimise the memory usage somehow (another topic). Regarding the packet sequence issue, I don't understand why getting rid of the "with" has changed anything. I must have not correctly understood "with" statements. If you have any suggestions, I'd like to hear, otherwise, thanks for your help!

Comment: I say: the with part hit a bug in python